# .Net- Action<T> Delegate error?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

i am using `Action<T> Delegate` to make a link between class and Form. the class connects to serial port and data received is displayed in the form. the `Action<T> Delegate` encapsulates a method in the Form that displays the data received. but the delegate is always showing null, does not encapsulate the method.

the class code is :

```
 public SerialPort mySerialPort;

    public Action<byte[]> DataReceived_Del;             //delegate for data recieved

    public string connect()
    {
        try
        {

            mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM14");
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = false;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += mySerialPort_DataReceived;
            mySerialPort.Open();

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            return "Connected";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Disconnected";
        }
    }


    //serial port data recieved handler
    public void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //no. of data at the port
            int ByteToRead = mySerialPort.BytesToRead;

            //create array to store buffer data
            byte[] inputData = new byte[ByteToRead];

            //read the data and store
            mySerialPort.Read(inputData, 0, ByteToRead);


            var copy = DataReceived_Del;
            if (copy != null) copy(inputData); 

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Received Event");
        }
    }
```

in the form we display the data:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Processes newprocess = new Processes();
        newprocess.DataReceived_Del += Display;


    }

    //Display
    public void Display(byte[] inputData)
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => TboxDisp.AppendText((BitConverter.ToString(inputData)))));
        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Display section");
        }
    }
```

the `DataReceived_Del` supposed to encapsulate the method `Display`, but it is `NULL`.

I can't see what is happening..

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

you should define newprocess outside the constructor , may this will resolve the

```
Processes newprocess;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    newprocess = new Processes();
    newprocess.DataReceived_Del += Display;


}
```

Comment: still the same.. but i believe it has something to do with the way i invoke the delegate.

Comment: The 'newprocess' variable might be have a 'constructor-local' scope but the object is still referenced by the event. So it won't be garbage collected, so it should still work, even if you cannot 'use' the newprocess variable outside of the constructor.

Comment: @Maarten: There is no event in the question

Comment: @Saurabh Sorry a typo. Read delegate instead of event, the principle still applies. The form object and the connect class are connected by the delegate, and therefore the connect class is referenced and won't be garbage connected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using += to add to the delegate, but the delegate is NULL to begin with. I'm not sure that will work. I would try = instead of +=.

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Processes newprocess = new Processes();
    newprocess.DataReceived_Del = Display;
}
```